# Query strings disappearing

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I have a website http://www.sumhr.com which is wordpress based.

Whenever I append a query string to it, the page on load removes the string and only displays the original URL. For example if I were to type `www.sumhr.com/?something` it would automatically truncate whatever is after the slash.

I have tried looking everywhere for a solution. Can't find any!

Comment: How does your htaccess look like?

Comment: We would need more info about that.

Comment: Check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply

There wasn't any htaccess file present on the server ,so I created one and pasted this text:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Comment: So? What's happening then? The problem still remains?

Comment: Yes, the problem still exists.

Comment: Just came back to say that I have solved this issue. It seems like a plugin called '404 redirected' was causing the issue. I deactivated it and now the problem no longer remains. Anyway, thanks guys for trying to help !